# Modify change event of Kendo UI Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to change the "change" event of a Kendo UI Dropdownlist, but unfortunately I haven't had any luck.  Here's the code I've tried so far: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/ukeV

Specifically, here's my dropdownlist initializer:

```
var onChange = function(e)
{
    alert("something changed");
};
// create DropDownList from input HTML element
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0,
    change: onChange
});
```

And this is my attempt to change that function later:

```
onChange = function(e){alert("attempt 1");};
var dropDownData = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropDownData.options.change = function(e){alert("attempt 2");}
dropDownData.refresh();
```

Specifically, I first tried just changing the onChange function, and then (when that didn't work), I tried changing the options.change function directly.  While the options.change function did change (when I examined it in chrome debugger), the dropdownlist's actual functionality remained unchanged.  I think I need to refresh the dropdownlist or something to make my edits actually take effect.  Does anyone know how I can actually get the kendo grid to refresh and display my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you've already found a work-around, but I thought I'd add some more explanations.

The reason why changing it like this

```
onChange = function(e){alert("attempt 1");};
```

doesn't work is that you're passing a function to the widget, and the widget calls that function at appropriate times. You're not passing a reference to the variable `onChange`. So changing the variable won't affect the widget.

The reason why

```
dropDownData.options.change = function(e){alert("attempt 2");}
```

doesn't work is that Kendo stores handlers in its own structure (which is necessary since you can bind multiple handlers for the same event!), so it doesn't call whatever is in `options.change` at any given moment in time.

However, there is a `setOptions` method, and with that you could've made your second approach work:

```
dropDownData.setOptions({
    change: function (e) {
        alert("attempt 2");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for in the first place!  Kendo documentation is unfortunately difficult to get through..  I also haven't tried it - would I have to call refresh() or anything afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a simple work-around.  When I put in the line

```
change: onChange
```

Kendo actually hardcoded in the function body into the dropDownData.options.change function, rather than referencing my named javascript function.  It looked like this in the debugger:

```
function(e)
{
  alert("something changed");
};
```

So my workaround was simply to use an anonymous function in the Kendo call.  So I changed change: to

```
change: function(e) { onChange(e) };
```

Then when I changed onChange later, kendo referenced the named javascript function and called my updated version.  Here's the working demo:  http://trykendoui.telerik.com/AkIW/2